# Store the Mongodb data into variable in sails js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am getting undefined value of recentdate variable.When I print the value using console then It print the value successfully.When I tried to hold the value inside the variable (recentdate) then It give the undefined.I want to store the value in variable so that I can use it further.

```
var recentdate ;
TimeHistory.find().sort([{ CreatedDated: 'DESC' }]).limit(1).exec(function (err, date) {
      console.log("RecentDate" + JSON.stringify(date[0].CreatedDated));//print the value sucessfully
      recentdate = JSON.stringify(date[0].CreatedDated);//getting undefined value
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a function as a callback (like you are passing the function to `.exec`, the function often runs **asynchronously**. That means the stuff inside the passed function will likely run after the code below. For example:

```
console.log('This will run first');
TimeHistory.find({}).exec(function() {
    console.log('This will run third and last');
});

console.log('This will run second');
```

The output of this code in the console is:

```
-> This will run first
-> This will run second
-> This will run third and last
```

So - if you try to use your `recentDate` below your `exec` method, the stuff inside has not run yet, and `recentDate` is still undefined.

There are many solutions, but a quick and easy one is to put your code using `recentDate` right inside your callback:

```
var recentDate;
TimeHistory.find({}).exec(function(err, results) {
    recentDate = results[0].date; // or whatever
    // now continue your processing here
});
// don't add any more code down here
```